# Can I geoquery nested Redis JSON objects

Tags: redis, node-redis, redisjson

I'm caching JSON objects in Redis whose properties include an array of geocoordinates. Something like this:

```
{
   "name": "bob",
   "points": [[31.0234, 35.3458], [38.0873, 34.8863]]
```

If I have a bounding box, how can I query for a list of objects which fall in that box?

Answer (score 1):

RediSearch currently does not have support for geo-box queries.

Comment: However it's prioritised on our roadmap and is the first next large items we'll tackle